# How to write to an array in Java using predetermined variables"

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write to a multidimensional array with some predetermined integers but am getting the error ***- The primitive type int of suit does not have a field number*** this is the code I am using when I get this error

```
    card[suit][number] = suit, number;
```

card is a multidimensional array I already created and I am trying to write to it using 2 integers I have created, suit and number

Comment: An array can only contain one object per slot. So in order to save two variables to it, you have to create a new class which holds those two numbers.

Comment: I'm still a fairly new programmer and am not really following this. Could you write some example code for me?

Comment: An array, like everything else in memory, contains single elements. That's like saying `int a = 2, 3;`, which doesn't work. If you really want this you can either make a class as QBrute has stated or even use a 2 dimensional array of arrays (i.e. a 3 dimensional array.)

Comment: @DylanChristensen: Can' you just provide the whole code (in case it is not too much)?

Comment: I used a work around with a list so I do not have the code anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to iterate through each element of your 2-d array and assign it a value.

```
    String[] suits = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Spades","Clubs"};
    String[] numbers = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

    // The size of the 2-d must be pre-initialized
    String[][] Cards = new String[suits.length][numbers.length];

    int i = 0; //suit index
    int j = 0; //number index

    for(String suit : suits){
        for(String number : numbers){
            Cards[i][j] = number+" of "+suit;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        j=0; // we have to return to the starting index to reset the number
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this definitely would have solved my problem but I created a work around with a list.